# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang

so i have:

1. Installed clang and configured it within VSCode, such as this: [image]

2) I run simple program:

```
 #include <iostream>

int main () {
    auto result = (10 < 20) > 0;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

3. Clang returns **clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

But if I try to compile it in BASH using: g++ main.cpp -o main, It works fine.

Im using Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

WHY DOES VSCODE RETURN ERROR WHILST COMPILING IN BASH WORKS FINE? How do I configure clang or any other compiler, so It does compile without any error?

THANK YOU